# Schedule Viewer GTFS

Tags: api, dictionary, gtfs

When i am trying to run Schedule Viewer from PC, it is looking for Google Map API Key, and it doesn't show the routeS on the Google Map, it never asked before, worked fine.

Any feedback from Google,or anybody facing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to sign up for an API key:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html

Then you run it like:

`python transitfeed/schedule_viewer.py --key=KEY --feed=FEED`

Where `KEY` is the API key or a file with the key, and `FEED` is the filename of the GTFS feed.